# Android Google Plus Sign in - Internal Error toast

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

When I click on the Google+ login button I get a toast naming an "internal error". No error is logged. Also I'm using at the same time the google map api's with no problem, so I think the key value is correct. So what's the problem?

The PlusClient initialization:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
    .setScopes("PLUS_LOGIN")  // Space separated list of scopes
    .build();
```

Comment: I've recreated the android app key in Google APIs Console several times, but still getting an "internal error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have removed from the Google API Console the OAuth 2.0 Client corresponding to my app... And now it's working. I have no clue about the reason of this behaviour, because I have strictly followed the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started).

Comment: Thank, I solve the problem too. Do anyone know why??

Comment: use this...it works   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361463/toast-internal-error-occur-with-integration-of-google-plus-in-android

Answer (score 1):

The scope you are using is wrong, try instead using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

It looks like the documentation references the same scope as your example, which I believe instead should be a library constant (com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN) that will ultimately resolve to the previously referenced scope.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. But I still get that internal error both using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login and com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN

Answer (score 0):

I've removed key created with new api interface and created client id with old edit api interface. and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you must fill the "Consent Screen" under APIs ad Auths , nothing else works if you do not fill the content in "Consent Screen".