# Android Google+ Signin "An internal error has occurred"

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I'm writing an app that allows users to login via Facebook or Google+.  What I've done is write an interface for the login, so that either one can be used.  Facebook login went just fine after hours of piecing together their documentation.  Google+ on the other hand has me baffled, or maybe I've just been staring at it too long.  I can generally find resolutions to my problems on SO, but it's been over a day of searching for an answer.

I implemented the [Getting Started with Google+ Platform](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) line by line.  I ran my application and I got the page that asked me to approve my app to access my Google+ account.  I click Approve and my app crashes.  :facepalm: I didn't add the Google+ API in console.  I was already using Google Maps, so I had skipped that part.

Now what happens?  I have an infinite loop of connection attempts resulting in Toasts saying "An internal error has occurred".  I no longer get a Google+ approval screen.  I've tried the following solutions from [SO 15762904](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762904/an-internal-error-occurred-with-integration-of-google-plus-login):

- Generated a new console key (even though Google Maps is working fine)
- Filled out my Consent Screen with email and product name
- Lots of answers involve removing the .setScopes() from the deprecated PlusClient API, doesn't apply here
- Double checked that the SHA fingerprint in the Developer Console is the same that was used to generate the API key
- Logged out of Google+ on the device

Here is the main activity code.  `mSession` is the variable I use for logins sessions.  I don't have buttons setup right now, I generally go for functionality before GUI.

```
private Login mSession;

/**************************************************************************
 * Activity life cycle methods
 **************************************************************************/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Populate the main content
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mSession = new GooglePlusLogin(this);
        mSession.openSession();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Call login session onStart() method
    mSession.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // Call login session onStop() method
    mSession.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mSession.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Here is the GoogleLogin class that implements the login interface.

```
public class GooglePlusLogin implements Login, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

private boolean mIntentInProgress;
private Activity mActivity;
private Context mContext;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private String mSessionToken;

public GooglePlusLogin(Activity activity) {
    mGoogleApiClient = null;
    mSessionToken = null;
    mIntentInProgress = false;
    mContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public boolean openSession() {
    boolean ret = false;

    Log.d(Helper.TAG, "openSession()");
    try {
        if(null != mContext) {
            Log.d(Helper.TAG, "null != mContext");

            mGoogleApiClient = 
                    new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                    .build();

            Log.d(Helper.TAG, "mPlusClient = " + mGoogleApiClient);

            ret = true;
        }
        else {
            throw new LoginException("GooglePlusLogin context NULL");
        }
    }
    catch(LoginException e) {
        Log.d(Helper.TAG, "" + e.toString());
    }

    Log.d(Helper.TAG, "Returning " + ret);

    return ret;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int respCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(Helper.TAG, "onActivityResult()");

    if(Helper.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN == reqCode) {
        mIntentInProgress = false;

        if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(Helper.TAG, "Not connected to Google Services, try again");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        else {
            Log.d(Helper.TAG, "Already connected to Google Services");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.d(Helper.TAG, "onStart()");

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.d(Helper.TAG, "onStop()");
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/*************************************************************************
 * Google+ Interface callbacks for GoogleApiClient
 *************************************************************************/
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.d(Helper.TAG, "onConnectionFailed()");

    if(!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            Log.d(Helper.TAG, "Try a Resolution");

            mIntentInProgress = true;

            //mActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(
            //      result.getResolution().getIntentSender(), 
            //      Helper.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN, 
            //      null, 
            //      0, 
            //      0, 
            //      0, 
            //      null
            //      );

            result.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, Helper.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
        }
        catch(SendIntentException e) {
            // Intent got canceled during processing, lets try and connect
            // again.
            Log.d(Helper.TAG, "Connect again");

            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    else {
        // Something terrible has happened with our connection to 
        // GooglePlay Services
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connHint) {
    // Do my stuff, but I never get to this point
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    Log.d(Helper.TAG, "onConnectionSuspended()");
    // The connection was suspended... lets try again
    mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();
}
```

Here are the pertinent sections of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"
    />    

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id_facebook"
        />
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/app_id_google"
        />
```

Here's the logcat output:

```
07-04 11:08:25.354: D/  App(15944): openSession()
07-04 11:08:25.354: D/  App(15944): null != mContext
07-04 11:08:25.364: D/  App(15944): mPlusClient = com.google.android.gms.common.api.b@42238088
07-04 11:08:25.364: D/  App(15944): Returning true
07-04 11:08:25.364: D/  App(15944):  Main AuthToken: null
07-04 11:08:25.364: D/  App(15944): onStart()
07-04 11:08:25.615: D/  App(15944): onConnectionFailed()
07-04 11:08:25.615: D/  App(15944): Try a Resolution
07-04 11:08:27.106: D/  App(15944): onActivityResult()
07-04 11:08:27.106: D/  App(15944): Not connected to Google Services, try again
07-04 11:08:27.176: D/  App(15944): onConnectionFailed()
07-04 11:08:27.176: D/  App(15944): Try a Resolution
07-04 11:08:28.538: D/  App(15944): onActivityResult()
07-04 11:08:28.538: D/  App(15944): Not connected to Google Services, try again
07-04 11:08:28.668: D/  App(15944): onConnectionFailed()
07-04 11:08:28.668: D/  App(15944): Try a Resolution
07-04 11:08:29.248: D/  App(15944): onActivityResult()
07-04 11:08:29.248: D/  App(15944): Not connected to Google Services, try again
07-04 11:08:29.479: D/  App(15944): onConnectionFailed()
07-04 11:08:29.479: D/  App(15944): Try a Resolution
07-04 11:08:30.970: D/  App(15944): onStop()
```

I hope this is something simple that I'm just overlooking.  The Get Started guide seemed to have some outdated information in it:

- mGoogleApiClient.addScope(Plus.API, null) crashes my app
- result.getSenderIntent() does not exist, you can see the two ways I've attempted to create the activity.

Much appreciation to anyone who can help.

Comment: The internal error is probably something else. Try clearing the cache in Google Play Services via the Google Settings App > Clear App Data in menu, and revoke access to the application from plus.google.com/apps. This should reset your session. Also try enabling verbose debugging, see the bottom of https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#frequently_asked_questions and look for any other errors in the console from google services (particularly anything involving GLS).

Comment: It's a little unclear where the "Clear App Data" option is.  I haven't submitted the app to Google Play yet.  I went into my Google+ settings and the 3rd Party apps are disconnected.  I haven't seen anything in my Google API Console under the Project that looks like a clearing of sessions.

Comment: Going into further debugging and looking at the logcat wrt GooglePlusPlatform, it says that "message":"Access not configured".  Which made zero sense to me because I have the GooglePlusApi enabled in the console.  I know my API key is good because the Google Map API connected, and showed me a map just fine.  However, I never generated the Client ID... I swear everything seems to be more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Google settings is an app on your device. Access not configured does sound like it not being enabled in the console - could it be that it is looking up a different client id than you expect? Check the sha and package name exactly match the ones in the console - watch out for errors like using a different key store than you expect.

Comment: Oohhh the device settings.  So many different options.  Clearing the cache is super helpful thanks for the tip!  But the Client ID was the main issue causing the Internal Error.  Now with all that resolved I have Scope issues.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361463/toast-internal-error-occur-with-integration-of-google-plus-in-android

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same issue and resolve by doing this.

On page Google api console.

1. Create a client ID
2. Application type should be installed application.
3. choose android (if it is for android) and Put your sha1 and package name.

**Now the important part.**

Click on `consent screen` below to the apis on left pannel menu
 and `fill the information`

You have done.Now run the application.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the important part...it solved my issues after trying about an hour.

Comment: + 1 Awesome thing. Was not able to find out the issue since there were no logs but then I came across this and bang, it started working. :)

Comment: @Nevaeh Have you turn on the service api named "Google+ API" in apis

Comment: yes.i did that too.I have a test application which is working fine with same sha1 and in same app.i tried creating new client id for my real app in same account and it is not working.i couldn't figure out why

Comment: Check with some parameters ones>
You have internet permission
You have create currect project (Check sha1 and package name)
Check Api (this should be on)
Check Consent screen (Is it fine)

Comment: If you have already set your SHA1 fingerprint (debug or release) in your google developer console and you still having this problem, check if you effectively build with your key, here is the way to set the key in Android Studio: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17992232/2486332

Answer (score 0):

just add the application details in https://console.developers.google.com/project
in console screen like EMAIL ADDRESS, PRODUCT NAME...

Answer (score 0):

you must fill the "Consent Screen" under APIs ad Auths , nothing else works if you do not fill the content in "Consent Screen".