# How to achieve google plus login functionality on own button in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

Hello I am trying to learn Google Sign In functionality in android. I did this and working fine according as expected.

Here it is showing default button of Google+ to sign, here is the layout and screenshot.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/loginGoogleButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
```

[image]

### Question

I don't want to have this style on my button. I want a simple button like android have

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginFaceboookButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="@string/login_with_facebook"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

How that button can achieve Google Sign In functionality or any way to make `com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton` to simple default button as in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.html this button is only visual representation

Comment: Take a look for this example https://github.com/bharv410/Deploy/blob/master/src/com/kidgeniusdesigns/deployapp/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Legal matters aside, the `SignInButton` *doesn't actually perform any special function*, it's just a visual widget. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.html):

> The Google sign-in button to authenticate the user. Note that this
>   class only handles the visual aspects of the button. In order to
>   trigger an action, register a listener using
>   `setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)`.

That is, if you have a Google+ sample running (i.e. using `GoogleApiClient`, the related callbacks, any of the APIs from `com.google.android.gms.plus`, &c) then you can replace the `SignInButton` with any other regular button and it will work just the same.

---

About the sample code: sorry, from the wording of your question I assumed you already had this part running.

You can find the tutorial for G+ integration [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started), in particular [this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) is the part about sign-in. Also, a sample project is distributed as part of the SDK (`<android-sdk>\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\plus`) with everything ready to go (although you need to enable the API in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), as described in the link, for it to work properly).

You can then just swap the `SignInButton` for a regular button.

Comment: from where i can find sample code of "Google+ sample running (i.e. using GoogleApiClient, the related callbacks, any of the APIs from com.google.android.gms.plus, &c)"

Comment: @Williams Edited answer, hope it's helpful.

Comment: so shouldn't I create my own custom button and achieve google sign functionality on it ?

Comment: @Williams There wouldn't seem to be any reason to do so. Plus it would seem that you're not actually allowed to. :-)

Comment: @matiash how can we set scope for our own button..?? like..
signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(new Scope[]{Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN, Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE});
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 4):

On https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/customize, this is written:

> Customizing the sign-in button
>
> You can customize the sign-in button so that it better fits your
>   site's design. You must follow the branding guidelines and use the
>   appropriate colors and icons in your custom button. You must also
>   ensure that your button appears with the same prominence as other
>   third-party login options. The branding guidelines also provide icon
>   assets that you can use to design your custom button.

It links to the [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines) which state

> These guidelines provide you with the design specification for various
>   Google+ buttons and badges. You can use these assets on your app
>   (website or mobile app) without pre-approval provided you follow these
>   basic guidelines. **Use of Google brands in ways not expressly covered
>   by this document is not allowed without prior written consent from
>   Google** (see the Guidelines for Third Party Use of Google Brand
>   Features for more information). Button use must also be in line with
>   our Buttons Policy.

This basically means you are not even allowed to use the Google+ code with your own button, unless you get "written consent", which I imagine will be hard to acquire.

(You are allowed to use a "custom" button IF if your button conforms to the guidelines, which it does not).

*I don't want to have this style on my button.*

You pretty much have to.
You can try to work around it, but your app will not survive in the Play Store long, and your developer account might face consequences (this is my own assumption, though)).

Answer (score 1):

**implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener** than setup your normal button

`btnGoogle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (internetChecker.isConnectingToInternet() == false) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.interet_connectivity),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        signInWithGplus();
                    }

                }
            });
/**
     * Sign-in into google
     * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
 protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
/**
* Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
 try {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.d("error",e.toString());
        return;
        }
}`

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
    Log.d("result.toString()", result.toString());
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,0).show();
    return;
    }
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
    // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
    mConnectionResult = result;
    if (mSignInClicked) {
    // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
    // resolve all
    // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
    resolveSignInError();
    }
    }

}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.d("onConnected", "onConnected::"+session.getIsRequestLogout());
    if (!session.getIsRequestLogout()) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    // Get user's information
    getGoogleProfileInformation();
    // Update the UI after signin

```
}
else
{
    signOutFromGplus();
}
```

}
/**
* Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
* */
private void getGoogleProfileInformation() {
try {
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
     Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    GoogleId=currentPerson.getId();
    UserName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    UserEmail = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
    /*String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
    String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
    String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
    Log.e("login", "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);*/

```
} else {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.google_profile_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.google_suspended_account), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (requestCode != RESULT_OK) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        }
        mIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
         }
    }

```
}
```

And one more thing follow this answer [Android Google+ Signin "An internal error has occurred"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577074/android-google-signin-an-internal-error-has-occurred#answer-26094784)

Answer (score -1):

use the play services for login

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements
  ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

 /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
 private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

 /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

 /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
  * us from starting further intents.
   */
  private boolean mIntentInProgress;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .build();
  }

 protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
  }

  protected void onStop() {
   super.onStop();

   if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
     mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
  }
  }


}
```